# Change the sort order when using grid view in Files (Nautilus)

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

Ubuntu Files 3.14.3 (also known as Nautilus) has two view modes - grid view & list view.

When in list view I can control which field is used to sort.

But when I go back to grid view it doesn't keep my sorting.

How can I control what to sort by when in grid view?

EDIT:

I realise you can change the default sort behaviour in preferences, but I don't want to change the default behaviour - I just want to sort the same you do when in list view in tile view.

Comment: I use Edit -> Preference -> Views tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus has a View menu which you can use to change the sort behaviour.

[image: View menu screencap]

Comment: thanks. I don't know why I didn't notice that little menu icon.